# Canonical Hostname

Tags: java, networking

Can anyone please tell me the proper concept of a canonical hostname and how can I check what is the canonical hostname on Windows?

Actually, I am facing a problem: I have a Java code which converts an input "server name" to its canonical hostname:

```
try {
    InetAddress in = InetAddress.getByName(REQUESTSERVER);
    REQUESTSERVER = in.getCanonicalHostName();
    System.out.println("Canonical REQUESTSERVER "+ REQUESTSERVER );
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("lookup failed");
}
```

Can the variable REQUESTSERVER have different values across a network?

Comment: @momojeet - Not sure I follow.  What is the value of REQUESTSERVER **before** you reassign the value?

Comment: @jmort :- its the name of a server like pns15a.crpny.ksrt.com..something like that...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the example listed [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-a-host-name-to-look-up-an-ip-address.html) for getting the CanonicalHostName() for google.
One of the output it gets for www.google.com is

```
Which Host:www.google.com
Canonical Host Name:po-in-f104.google.com
Host Name:www.google.com
Host Address:72.14.253.104
```

When i ran the same program on my local box i got the output as

```
Which Host:www.google.com
Canonical Host Name:74.125.227.49
Host Name:www.google.com
Host Address:74.125.227.49
```

So , depending how the reppective DNS is configured , variable REQUESTSERVER will have different values accross a network

Comment: ok go it , thanks....can you tell me how to get that name on windows and linux machines...

Comment: The different values:- How can i get it without this piece of code..I need both for linux and windows!

Comment: As far as i know , if both the machines are on the same network with the same DNS server, the canonical names will be same for both of 'em.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly in the (common) case of virtual hosting where a single physical host provides different virtual websites.  In this case the hostname used by the client to access the server will be available from the Java Servlet method  `ServletRequest.getServerName()`.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777575/getting-the-real-virtual-host-name-under-an-application-server).